# Is it possible to unmarshall encrypted xml files using JAXB in java

Tags: java, encryption, jaxb, aes, jasypt

AES Encrypted file named temp.xml :

```
31E7450D33BAB4C4D5C624B9376B4BB3532E5BBAFDE0D4300C9C46C86DC7894CBC7A9AA11069700FDF45E2C5E6947CB5268BD673AB85B4DCCAA3ECAE411BD0763F199A031FD0A78E2F3EDDDE386DFD1EEAB
```

Decrypted file named temp.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><root><temp></temp></root>
```

I searched about it but didn't get anything to try.

I have read about Jasypt but Jasypt is capable of unmarshalling encrypted XML **values** to decrypted strings in the corresponding Java objects by creating an 'adapter' class.

Please let me know If it is possible with adapter or through some other way & if yes then suggest me.
You can also suggest any other way of securing files.
Note : As of now we are reading XML in encrypted form  then decrypting it & passing XML in decrypted string form to jaxb to unmarshall it. please suggest solution other than this.

Comment: Create an intermediate decrypted InputStream and unmarshal that.

Comment: Try using the `CipherInputStream` class.